# Dedekind Zeta Function in Mathematica (at least for quadratic number field)

Tags: special-functions, packages, number-theory

Does there exist some way to use Mathematica to compute the Dedekind Zeta function for an arbitrary algebraic number field? Or does there exist some package to do this?

I am actually only interested in computing it for quadratic number fields, and in particular the field $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$, so if there's some way to do that in Mathematica I'd be quite happy. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function#Relations_to_other_L-functions) I should be able to express it as a product of the Riemann Zeta function and some particular  Dirichlet L function given some choice of parameters for the Dirichlet L function. This means it should be expressible as `Zeta[s]*DirichletL[k,j,s]` for some particular choice of `k` and `j`. Can I use Mathematica to compute what `k` and `j` would be for $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$?

EDIT: after playing around with it, it looks like we have `Zeta[s] * DirichletL[5, 3, s]` is the correct expression for the Dedekind Zeta function for $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$, at least in the sense that the values at negative integers agree with the values [here](https://planetmath.org/valuesofthededekindzetafunctionofmathbbqsqrt5atnegativeintegers). That $5$ is the discriminant of the quadratic number field, so we have as our expression

`Zeta[s] * DirichletL[NumberFieldDiscriminant[Sqrt[5]], ????, s]`

where "3" gives the right answer when substituted in for "????" above. This is Mathematica's [index to the correct Dirichlet character](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletCharacter.html) that I determined gave the right answer just by trying a few things. Is there some programmatic way to do this for an arbitrary quadratic number field?

Comment: Hi, look [this](https://www.math.waikato.ac.nz/~kab/zetapack.pdf)